# Why isn't viewDidLoad executed when a UIViewController's view becomes visible?

Tags: ios, uikit, viewcontroller, memory-warning

I am reading a book on iOS programming. Suppose that we have two viewcontrollers (each of them have its own view), at any time, I can only see view of one of them. When the APP is running, I sent a "memory warning" via simulator. According the book, I should observe the hidden viewcontroller's viewDidLoad been triggered again when I "force" the hidden one to show up. But I didn't see it happen.

In other words, "memory warning" are supposed to destroy the view which is not on the screen. But I can't see it.

The book are written for iOS5. I am wondering if there is some behavior change in iOS6+

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the behavior changed in iOS 6.  Starting in iOS 6, a UIViewController does **not** unload its view when the system sends a low-memory warning.

The [`viewDidUnload` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW36) is quite clear:

> Deprecated in iOS 6.0. Views are no longer purged under low-memory conditions and so this method is never called.

Answer (score 1):

it is called when its VIEW is used the first time. The first time it is loaded.

So when someone calls: `viewController.view` and `viewController.isViewLoaded` is `NO` then the view is loaded and `viewDidLoad` is called.

The view is never unloaded (since iOS 6).

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` corresponds with when the UIViewController's view is created. `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` are the key methods involved when the UIViewController's view becomes visible.

Comment: Thanks. I just edit my question so that it is more clear. I am just wondering why "memory warning" didn't causes the view destroyed

Comment: A memory warning does not destroy objects with strong references (aka retained objects). It executes methods that you have to implement to free up memory. If you do not free enough memory, your app can ultimately be terminated.

Comment: it is called when it's VIEW is used the first time = that is not its initialization

Answer (score 0):

viewDidLoad will get called only when the viewController is initialized.

May be you are using a navigation controller or tab bar view controller to bring up your view controller - both of them do not deallocate your view controller and hence viewDidLoad is not called.

Comment: it is called when it's VIEW is used the first time = that is not its initialization